# Alternative to Jeditable for editable table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

I have been trying to use Jeditable to make my html table editable. However upon much research I found that it is very difficult (if not impossible without a backend) to validate the input.

I really would prefer NOT to use any sort of plugin and simply write/use a bit of Javascript that would make cells editable and allow me to attach jQuery Validator to the input. The data will never get submitted to a backend (will return to default on page refresh) so the solution doesn't need to be complex...will only be using html and Javascript.

The problem with most code snippets I have found using Google is that they seem to get stuck when you click inside a cell and clicking outside the cell doesn't save/submit the change.

Does anyone have a snippet they have used successfully and/or experience using a snippet with Validator?

Comment: if you want everything to be editable but not saved, why don't you use inputs inside the cells.. ?

Comment: it is not that difficult to validate input, just make your own type of editable control, see for instance http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin

Comment: @vittore thanks for the link, I am already using jQuery Validator on a login form so I would prefer to continue to use that. However, if I decide to stay with Jeditable I will likely use your link as a reference to create a mask for the input as I believe you can create custom masks within the Jeditable plugin.

Comment: @amosrivera I like the idea of making cells look permanent until clicked...however I may try playing around with some CSS and see if I can get the same effect.

Comment: indeed, you can change the styles using :focus pseudo class..

Comment: @amosrivera Thanks for the tip, I will definitely try that as it would make the whole process easier.

Comment: also I would strongly agree with @amosrivera as jeditable has an awful performance especially if you are going to use big tables ( hundred rows with dozen columns used to kill it a year ago )

Comment: I have already began editing the table to use `<input>`'s as a way to make its contents editable, and will work with CSS to try and make the cells look normal until they receive `:focus` Thanks @amosrivera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, according to information I got in your [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251107/change-javascript-function-to-edit-cells-instead-of-append-them/), you can change that function to:

```
function appendTable(id)
 {
     var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
     var i = 0;
     var rows = tbody.rows;
     for (var r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
         var row = rows[r];
         for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
             var cell = row.cells[c];
             cell.firstChild.value = subset[i++]; // the only part changed
         }
     }
 }
```

when your html looks like:

```
<table id="alphabetTable" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header1</th>
            <th>Header2</th>
            <th>Header3</th>
            <th>Header4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "text" size="1" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" size="1" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" size="1" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" size="1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "text" size="1" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" size="1" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" size="1" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" size="1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "text" size="1" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" size="1" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" size="1" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" size="1" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you could see, I rely on `firstChild` property, however it can be dangerous, e.g. when your html looks like:

```
<td> <input type = "text" size=1 /> </td>
```

then at least FF returns `<TextNode textContent=" ">` as firstChild. Not to depend on this issue you can go with:

```
cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = subset[i++];
```

PS. All I wrote was based on info I got from another question, if something wrong - comment and I will try to change ;)

Comment: Seriously amazing how quickly you can knock that out. I wish I knew my way around javascript that well..only started on Monday so got a ways to go! Thanks again, it works perfectly! I went with `cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = subset[i++];` method as I see how that other one could be dangerous as editing continues.

Comment: I am going to start working on the next part which is adding rows and having them auto populate upon add, based on the value of the last cell in the original set of cells (essentially running the `getPos` function again). Should comment you in of these posts later if I post a question about this next step?

Comment: @tehaaron: I'm going to sleep ;) tomorrow I can take a look at your questions; up to you, I can also find them in your profile ;)