# Change Javascript function to edit cells instead of append them

Tags: javascript, html-table, append

Sorry for the vagueness of my question. Let me start from scratch.

I currently have this: http://jsfiddle.net/kmg4x/1/

and this other question I posted is related: [Alternative to Jeditable for editable table cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250728/alternative-to-jeditable-for-editable-table-cells)

Although I eventually want to do away with the form on the top and make the cells editable, this question is primarily about changing the table contents as opposed to adding new cells.

As you can see, if you enter a single letter into the top left input box and click out, it appends the table with the remaining part of the array (after a `slice`). I would like instead for it to change the contents of the existing cells.

I have tried changing `cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode` to `innerHTML` but it ended up doing the exact same thing. My guess is that it has to do with changing the `var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];` to `var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("td")[0];` but when i do that it just breaks.

Is there an `editCell()` equivalent of `tbody.insertRow(r)` Maybe `td.innerHTML(r)`?

Eventually I will add a button that can add and remove rows.

Hope this is better.

Comment: are you wish to append a 4x4 table?

Comment: Very broad question. You'll get better answers by narrowing the scope of your question. I read your question and really can't understand what you are trying to do. You should always mention what you've tried, the expected behavior, and the actual behavior. Questions that sound like, please do this for me are likely to be ignored. Best way to get your question answered, create a http://jsfiddle.net that shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JuanMendes thanks for the advice, I updated the question and hopefully it is more clear now. Let me know if it isnt.

Comment: I'm glad your rework of the question got you an answer. Sometimes I can sound rude when I tell someone to improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: thank you for editing question, I see the problem, try to change code of your function `appendTable` (however this name is not good anymore ;):

```
function appendTable(id)
 {
     var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
     var i = 0;
     var rows = tbody.rows;
     for (var r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
         var row = rows[r];
         for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
             var cell = row.cells[c];
             cell.innerHTML = subset[i++];
         }
     }
 }
```

your mistake was that you inserted rows all the time, and inserted cells into them. Instead you use arrays `rows` of `tbody` element (obvivious it gives you all rows of the table), and `rows` in its turn has array of `cells` - all cells of row. So now you can 'reuse' them to update table content.

Notice, this function use table, but not creates it (your entiry function created table rows and cell).

Comment: I tried this and it is starting to work! However it editing the table in a strange manner by doing r1c1, r2c2, ect see: http://jsfiddle.net/kmg4x/2/

Comment: @tehaaron: I noticed and fixed it, sorry; just forgot to loop through rows ;)

Comment: Ah you beat me to it! I was making progress, but had a few things out of order. Thanks!..A side question if I might..would this take much editing if I were to create input boxes inside all the cells to make them editable? so instead of editing the whats inside `<td></td>` it would be editing what was inside of `<td><input type="text" size="1" /></td>` ?...this is related to the overall goal and my other question I linked to.

Comment: @tehaaron: take a look at my reply [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250728/alternative-to-jeditable-for-editable-table-cells), was I right with 'question' and what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your life easier by assigning ids to each cell in the table, e.g.

```
<table>
    <tr id=tr_1>
        <td id=td_a1>a</td>
        <td id=td_a2>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id=tr_2>
        <td id=td_b1>a</td>
        <td id=td_b2>a</td>
    </tr>
 <table>
```

etc.The ids this way are very easy to generate programatically, and then use:

```
function changeCell(id, txt) {
    var td = document.getElementbyId (id);
    td.innerHTML=txt;
}
```

Comment: But will it stay simple when I add a button later that will actually create more rows and cells and then auto-populate them with the next letters in the array? Wouldn't I have to write into the function a snippet to increase both the TD id number `td_x++` and `tr_y++` ? Would it still be simpler?

Comment: I'm assuming that the table will remain small as your example. Then `for (int i=0; i<maxrows, i++) { for j=0; j<maxcolx; j++) {var tr=document.createElement ("tr") tr.setAttribute ("id", "td_"+i+"_"+j);` etc. Will work for a few rows very easily

Comment: I also see that Maxym also gave you another answer closer to what you wanted to do.

Comment: I like your approach if the table was going to remain a static size. unfortunately it will be changing sizes based on button clicks later on and I think appending your approach would require and extra set of loops that I would rather not write. I may come back to this later if I find that it would in fact be easier. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

use `document.createElement('<input type="text"/>')` instead of `document.createTextNode` and generate input box

Comment: `document.createElement('<input type="text"/>')` is not cross browser; However, `document.createELement('input')` is and has the same effect since the default type is text

Answer (score 0):

if you want to edit cells of a table you need to ... this is hard to tell you

how many inpt field you have?

how do you want to edit the table? replace the text of the cell to a new input and then edit this, or create a complete new form where you can eneter row/column num and then edit the cell. or how?

this is not so easy. you should tell your wish ho to make this work.